# CDI bean with Application Scope doesn't recognize name of the Session Bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am getting an error in the AllUsersBean class in the default constructor.
It doesn't recognize subBean in this line users.add(subBean.clone()); 
I am using subBi.clone to clone submited info by the user to the UsersList that is called users.
Thank you for any advice.

This is error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-
compile) on project Test: Compilation failure
[ERROR] ......(here was path to this class) AllUsersBean.java:[25,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable subBean
```

To solve the problem I trid to add getter and setter for appBean in UserBean class but it doesn't work.

```
package testpkg;

/*Importing required java libraries */
import javax.inject.Named; 
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Named("appBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class AllUsersBean {

   private List<UserBean> users;

   public AllUsersBean(){
      users = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
      users.add(subBean.clone());
   }

   public List<UserBean> getUsers() {
      return users;
   }

   public void setUsers(List<UserBean> users) {
      this.users = users;
   }
}
```

```
package testpkg;

/*Importing required java libraries */
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Named; 
import javax.inject.Inject; 
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@Named("subBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{

   private String fname;

   @Inject
   private AllUsersBean appBean;

   public UserBean() {
     this.fname = null;
   }

   public String getFname() {
       return fname;
   }

   public void setFname(String fname) {
       this.fname = fname;
   }

    public AllUsersBean getAppbean() {
       return appBean;
   }

   public void setAppbean(AllUsersBean appBean) {
       this.appBean =appBean;
   }
}
```

Comment: it isn't just provided by maven dependency

Comment: @Jigar Joshi what do you mean by that?

Comment: maven doesn't find that class at compile time, so that package containing that class is provided as dependency to package being compiled ?

Comment: so is something what I am missing to add in my code?

Comment: which maven module contains `AllUsersBean` class ?

Comment: Are you sure your tags of JSF are correct in this? nothing in this code is JSF, nor any packages used.

Comment: It is JSF. I just didn't post my .xhtml files bc I was not sure if its relevant. I think my tags are ok.

Comment: The error doesn't have anything to do with jsf, web or web services at all. It's a missing variable definition. This concept is explained at page 1 of all basic java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a field with name subBean to AllUsersBean and make you initialization in method with annotation @PostConstruct? And in general using clone is not a good practice